# How to pull out the Contacts whose associated account has highest annual revenue?

Tags: salesforce, apex, soql

I want to pull out all those contacts whose associated Account have highest annual revenue and I use below SOQL query

```
select name, account.AnnualRevenue from contact where account.AnnualRevenue=(select MAX(account.AnnualRevenue) from contact)
```

and I also used below SOQL Query

```
select name, account.AnnualRevenue from contact where account.AnnualRevenue=(select MAX(AnnualRevenue) from Account)
```

In both the queries I am getting **"Unknown error parsing query"** error
Please help me how to achieve this. Thanks in advance

Comment: Pls tag correctly. the tag "oracle-apex" refers to an Oracle dev tools named "Oracle Apex". Not the same as the salesforce programming language called "apex".

Answer (score 1):

Your 1st query:

```
select name, 
       account.AnnualRevenue        --> you are selecting column from ACCOUNT ...
from contact                        --> ... but - there's no ACCOUNT table in FROM clause
where account.AnnualRevenue = 
  (select MAX(account.AnnualRevenue) --> you are selecting column from ACCOUNT ...
   from contact                      --> ... but - there's no ACCOUNT in FROM clause
  );
```

Similar error causes problem in your 2nd query.

---

It would be easier to assist if you posted tables' description; without that information, we can only guess which column belongs to which table. My guess:

```
SQL> with
  2  account (account_id, contact_id, annualrevenue) as
  3    (select 100, 1, 100 from dual union all
  4     select 101, 2, 200 from dual
  5    ),
  6  contact (contact_id, name) as
  7    (select 1, 'Little' from dual union all
  8     select 2, 'Foot'   from dual
  9    ),
```

Based on such sample data, first *sort* rows from the `account` table by `annualrevenue` in descending order (which means that highest revenue is on the top):

```
 10  --
 11  temp as
 12    (select account_id, contact_id, annualrevenue,
 13       rank() over (order by annualrevenue desc) rnk
 14     from account
 15    )
```

Finally, join `contact` and `temp` and fetch row(s) that ranked as the highest:

```
 16  select c.name, t.annualrevenue
 17  from contact c join temp t on t.contact_id = c.contact_id
 18  where t.rnk = 1;

NAME   ANNUALREVENUE
------ -------------
Foot             200

SQL>
```

---

Even if your tables don't look like that, now you have a working example which should help you write your own query.

Comment: This is SOQL, salesforce's dialect that doesn't have "with"(well, it has but not for how you use it), "temp", joins syntax is bit different too... Your answer won't compile

Comment: Huh, I was fooled by tag I'm following (oracle-apex) and suggested SQL syntax. True - I don't know Salesforce at all, but - nonetheless - I *hope* that comments I wrote make sense because the OP was using column from table that isn't referenced within that scope. As of the WITH factoring clause, it can be rewritten to a subquery (no problem with that); would that help, then, @eyescream? As of JOIN: how is it used? Is it a comma-separated list of tables which are then joined within the WHERE clause? If so, no problem with that either. I mean, I can rewrite code I suggested that way.

Answer (score 0):

Don't think you can pull it off with 1 query, not if you want to be sure you grabbed all accounts with same top revenue.

If the field would be unique - this could be a good way

```
SELECT Id, Name,
    (SELECT LastName, Email FROM Contacts)
FROM Account
ORDER BY AnnualRevenue DESC
LIMIT 1
```

It'll grab 1 account - but however many contacts are linked to it. The problem of course is if you have multiple with same value...

---

2 queries:

```
SELECT AnnualRevenue FROM Account ORDER BY AnnualRevenue DESC LIMIT 1
```

and then

```
SELECT Id, LastName, Email
FROM Contact
WHERE Account.AnnualRevenue = :x
```